# Mysql query for search possible Friends

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a friends table that keeps track of relationships in my DB
The connections between users are bi-directional. 
I'm working on a "Possible Friends" feature, where i need to show all the friends of friends who's not my friend and sort them by descending from total common friends

Structure table "FRIENDS":

```
 user_id    |    friend_id    
    1               2               
    2               1                
    1               3               
    3               1               
    3               4               
    4               3               
    2               6   
    6               2
    3               6
    6               3
```

For example, possible friends for user_id = 1, this is 6 and 4.

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
 user_id    |    Possible id    |    id common friends      |    Total common friends    
                 (friend_id)
    1               6                       2                           2
    1               6                       3                           2
    1               4                       3                           1
```

How can I do such query?

THANK YOU

Comment: "Possible friend" = "friends of my friends who's not my friend". You need  to divide and conquer. 1. Pull the list of "My friends" (Set A) 2. Pull the list of friends of [Set A] (results in Set B) 3. Substract from (Set B) people you already friend with -- i.e [Set A] (results in Set C) 3. Pull the list of friends of [Set C] (results in Set D) 4. Count matches between [Set D] and [Set A] 5. Order by this count. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT f1.user_id, 
       f2.friend_id as "Possible id (friend_id)", 
       f1.friend_id as "id common friends",
       f3.total as "Total common friends"
FROM friends f1
INNER JOIN friends f2 on f1.friend_id = f2.user_id and f1.user_id <> f2.friend_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT fa.user_id, 
           fb.friend_id, 
           count(fb.friend_id) as total 
    FROM friends fa
    INNER JOIN friends fb on fa.friend_id = fb.user_id and fa.user_id <> fb.friend_id
    GROUP BY fa.user_id, fb.friend_id
) f3 on f3.user_id = f1.user_id and f3.friend_id = f2.friend_id
```

Comment: I'm speechless! Thank you very much! You helped me a lot =)